# What to do about tag collisions when merging repositories in git

Tags: git

I am merging three git repos using read-tree. There are tag name conflicts. Is there some way to 'fetch' from a remote and map the tag names in the event of conflicts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, sort of (so maybe "no" is more accurate but you can get what you want, with work).  That is, there's no way to map tags *conditionally*, but it's easy enough to map tags *always*.

When you run `git fetch remote` (without `--tags`), `git fetch` uses the configuration entries under `remote.remote.fetch` to control which ref-names are fetched.  When you run `git fetch remote --tags` it behaves as if you had given it `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` on the command line, or—equivalently—behaves as if all entries in the config were temporarily replaced with that one single refspec.

Look at the actual refspec for branches, and you'll see that, e.g., `remote.origin.fetch` is set to `+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`.<sup>1</sup>  The `+` causes forced updates (i.e., update even if the result is not a fast forward) and the remainder copies the remote's `refs/heads/master` to your local `refs/remotes/origin/master` (creating it if needed).

Tags live in the `refs/tags/` name-space (vs branches, in `refs/heads/`, and remote-branches in `refs/remotes/`).  There is no such thing as "remote tags", but you can just make it up, the way there used to be no such things as "notes" and now there is a `refs/notes/` name-space.  So:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/origin/*'
```

will add a line to the configuration for `remote.origin.fetch` that will make `git fetch origin` bring over their tags, but store them in this new "remote tags" name-space.

Once the fetch completes (and you've run other fetches for other remotes) you can do your own mapping for whatever winds up in `refs/rtags/*`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Assuming you're not set up as a mirror.

Comment: This is a great answer, thanks. Can you please help me understand how to handle collisions with tags in an upstream repo? [My question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76618994/7850)

Comment: @torek I tried but the git config --add remote.origin.fetch 'refs/tags/*:refs/rtags/origin/*' course the tag to go both in refs/tags and refs/rtags/origin is there any way to only get them in refs/rtags/origin?